# Conflicts after merge from Master multiple times

Tags: git, github, merge, git-fork

I am new to Git and GitHub and tried to contribute to a project, so I made a fork. The project contains tons of folders with files and the only thing I did is, to **add two folders** with some files in them and **modify one single file**. After a while I wanted to keep up to date with the original master and merged from upstream as recommended in https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/ - so I did a did a `git merge upstream/master`. This introduced lots of changes into master of my fork.

Now, some months later I decided to sync my fork again and did a `git merge upstream/master` again. This brought me in like 10 conflicts, which are on files, which I did not touch myself. Of course I could try to merge them manually, but I want to understand, what's going on, so that I do not destroy others work.

Questions:

- Why do those conflicts occur on the 2nd merge from upstream?
- Could I have somehow changed the base of my fork to the top-most (is that what rebase does?)
- How can I find out the "change paths" of the two conflicting versions (where did they come from?)

If it helps, the following is the fork I am talking about: https://github.com/0815fox/DefinitelyTyped

Comment: It is hard to say what is the cause of the conflicts, but it means that either you have committed since pulling last from the upstream, or the upstream's history has be rewritten, or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Likely the original repo was rebased, or your local repo was, and you would need to do a fetch and hard reset to get back in sync.
- It's very unlikely you unknowingly did this. It's not normally possible, and the only way I can fathom it is to create a bare branch by resetting back to first commit and reverse cherry pick commits one at a time. That is not what rebase does. Rebase can be used to squash commits together and to move new commits behind ancestral commits on an upstream branch for a fast forward merge.

You can inspect the merge paths of all branches with git log.

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
```

If you're interested in when a particular line in a file was made, such as when investigating a conflict, use git blame.

```
git blame -- filename
```

My suggestion to fix after you're done investigating is to create a new branch with your changes in tact, reset your upstream branch, then cherry pick your range of commits over.

```
git checkout -b mybranch
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
git cherry-pick ^your1stSHA..yourLastSHA
```

Comment: Wow, this already helped a lot. Still, one small thing is unclear: I already commited my changes and pushed to origin/master. a git reset --hard origin/master will not do anything as I do not have modifications atm, or am I wrong with that? Can I somehow reset my master to upstream/master and cherry-pick from my branch, discarding all other stuff?

Comment: Yes, reset to the original project remote `upstream/master` and cherry pick your changes.